# ArcGIS Scale Error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, scale

My scales are broken, I can't enter scales manually, how can I go back to the old one?
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: revert to arcgis standard scales 1:100/000 1:/200.000 1:/500.000

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

Use the option to reset the default scales:

[image]

Try this if the above did not work:

Close ArcMap and follow the below:

1. Navigate to `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local` and rename the ESRI folder to ESRI_old
2. Navigate a step back to `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming` and rename the Esri folder to ESRI_old
3. Launch ArcMap and check.

**Note:** Administrator is your user profile